# Undefined Parent Object

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

I'm writing a Family Tree app and I'm having trouble connecting a child with a parent dynamically.  I keep getting an error that the parent is undefined.  As the same function was used to create the parent, I'm lost as to how to identify the parent other than passing it through a variable name when the function is called again.

Huge thanks to anyone that can point me in the right direction.  I'm obviously not very well versed in javascript.

Update:  I was able to solve the problem by assigning each of the function calls to an appropriately names variable.  Thanks to @Oriol's help below!

```
var rafael_bravo = addFamilyMember("rafael_bravo", "Rafael Bravo", "-", "-", "-", god, "GeneralPartner");
var calixta_otero = addFamilyMember("calixta_otero", "Calixta Otero", "-", "-", "-", rafael_bravo, "LimitedPartner");
var omar_bravo = addFamilyMember("omar_bravo", "Omar Bravo", "-", "-", "-", rafael_bravo, "LimitedPartner");


    function addFamilyMember (child,name,dob,dod,img,parent,link) {

                    child = new primitives.orgdiagram.ItemConfig();
                    child.name = name;
                    child.birth = dob;
                    child.death = dod;
                    child.image = "includes/images/" + img + ".png";
                    child.templateName = "familyTemplate";
                    parent.items.push(child);

                    jQuery(".basicdiagram").orgDiagram("update", primitives.orgdiagram.UpdateMode.Refresh);
                    return child;
                }
```

Comment: Off-topic: when you redefine `child`, the element you passed as argument won't vary outside the function, so the argument `child` is useless.

Comment: You say *the same function was used to create the parent*, but I don't think so. `parent` is just an argument which could be undefined.

Comment: @Oriol - That's what I was afraid of...  How would you fix this?

Comment: You should post the code you use to call `addFamilyMember`

Comment: I added the function call to my code above.  Thanks a million for taking a look.

Comment: The problem is that `parent` is `"god"`, so `parent.items` is `undefined` (unless you have added `String.prototype.items = someObject`). Instead, you should pass an object like `{items:[]}`

Comment: But `"god"` is an string instead of an object! Maybe you should use `god` instead of `"god"`?

Comment: I had already created the "god" parent using 'god = new primitives.orgdiagram.ItemConfig();'

Comment: Better use `var` to define: `var god = new primitives.orgdiagram.ItemConfig();`. And you have defined `god`, but `"god"` is an string, not your variable! I think you should read a tutorial

Comment: Removing the quotes works for connecting a child to the god object (as I created the god object initially), but it doesn't work when I try to connect a grandchild to the child. Thus, the second and third function calls above fail (parent is undefined). I added more code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
var names = {};
function addFamilyMember (id,name,dob,dod,img,parentId,link) {
    var child = new primitives.orgdiagram.ItemConfig();
    child.name = name;
    child.birth = dob;
    child.death = dod;
    child.image = img ? "includes/images/" + img + ".png" : "";
    child.templateName = "familyTemplate";
    names[id] = child;
    names[parentId].items.push(child);
    jQuery(".basicdiagram").orgDiagram("update", primitives.orgdiagram.UpdateMode.Refresh);
    return child;
}
addFamilyMember("rafael_bravo", "Rafael Bravo", "-", "-", "", "god", "GeneralPartner");
addFamilyMember("calixta_otero", "Calixta Otero", "-", "-", "", "rafael_bravo", "LimitedPartner");
addFamilyMember("omar_bravo", "Omar Bravo", "-", "-", "", "rafael_bravo", "LimitedPartner");
```

Also note that if you use `"-"` as `img`, browser will try to download `includes/images/-.png`, so better use something falsy (like empty string `""`, or `void(0)`, or `false`) and then check it. I have used an empty string, but some browsers will try to download current page as image, so better check `child.image` when you create the image.

Comment: Awesome!  That should do the trick!  I actually just came up with a similar solution of assigning each of the addFamilyMember function calls to an appropriately named var.